# Can you set a program to open "always on top" by default in XFCE4 (xfwm4)?

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, xfce

For some reason I can't seem to find the answer to this. Setting "always on top" in the program's titlebar doesn't seem to persist after the program shuts down or the computer reboots. Please note that I do not use (and do not intend to use) XFCE sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could install and run Devil's Pie. I use it for controlling window positioning, which workspaces to open in, decoration, and many other features. Here's a great documentation for how to use it: [Devil's Pie documentation](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie)

Also, an example to make `gkrellm` show on all workspaces, on top, in the top left corner:

```
(if (is (application_name) "gkrellm")
    (begin
        (println "set gkrellm")
        (undecorate)
        (geometry "153x604-0+26")
        (skip_pager)
        (above)
        (pin)
    )
)
```

Comment: That's really cool. It actually may solve a few more "problems" for me than the one in the question, and it's in the Arch official repos. Thanks for pointing out a new toy. :)

Comment: For anybody stumbeling across this answer like me many years later, I want to add that Devilspie as suggested by @slybloty is not maintained anymore.

The successor Devilspie2 is a also available on debian. It is LUA script based so the syntax is not compatible to the Devilspie.

Comment: <http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie> is no longer found (and Google does not find _devilspie_ in the domain). Thanks to @Hotsndot, I guess that <https://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/> is the home for _Devilspie2_.